# Is there a function that allows me to isolate the units digit from a number?

Tags: functions

You can isolate every number except for the units digit quite easily by taking the floor of n/10, however is there a way to isolate only the units digit?

As an example:
Using the formula above I can turn 123 into 12 by taking the floor 123/10.
But I want to turn 123 into 3

Another one is:
I can turn 1745 into 174 by taking the floor of 1745/10
But I want to turn 1745 into 5

Any help is appreciated, I have tried and I cannot figure out a nice way of doing this.
Thank you :)

Comment: Such a function is $$f(x)= x \pmod{10}$$

Comment: I think you have to be more precise on what you consider a function. You could for example compose the projection $\mathbf{Z} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbf{Z}/10\mathbf{Z}$ with the injection $\mathbf{Z}/10\mathbf{Z} \to \mathbf{Z}$ mapping $1 + 10\mathbf{Z}$ to $1$, etc.

Comment: Thank you for a way nicer way than my own convoluted solution :)

Comment: Fair, I was looking for a way to include the conversion of some number into only it's unit digit in a larger formula

Comment: Most of the time, $mod$ is a function that would be available ("remainder after division", a lot of languages use %)

Answer (score 2):

Actually I figured it out
Let's say that my n=1634
I can take the floor of n/10 which would give me 163
Then I can multiply that by 10 to give me 1630
Then I can subtract that from n
Which would be 1634-1630=4
Therefore, the units digit is 4